# Orientation of git flow feature merges?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-flow

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16440520/18149) the author talks about:

> "You normally don't merge feature branches repeatedly into develop.
>   You merge develop into the feature branches (i.e. the other way
>   around) or rebase the feature branches onto the HEAD of develop
>   (recommended)."

Now when I've done feature branch merges without `git flow` in the past I've always just switched my `master` branch and then run `git merge <latest-feature-branch-commit>` and that merges it back into master after merging any conflicts and committing.  So in `git flow` assuming the same is true with the `develop` branch acting as the `master` branch in this case (or at least that's how I've always thought of it, since you branch your `feature/*` branches off of it in `git flow`), what does the author of that post mean about "you merge develop into feature branches"?  Does he mean you should be in the `feature/n` branch and then merge `develop` from there?  That sounds a bit obsurd unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git [rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing) is opposite of git merge. in git rebase we take changes from master/develop branch and add them to feature branch, without creating any commit history.
git rebase also doing merge, but in opposite direction(main->feature).
it may be sounding absurd to you but there are several advantages of using git rebase as listed [here](https://itnext.io/advantages-of-git-rebase-af3b5f5448c6)